# How to set child theme path

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to *set* the child theme path. Instead of having child theme templates loaded from the standard location I want to load them from a different location.

For example I have themes:

```
wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen
wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen_child
```

where twentyfifteen_child has style.css and functions.php along with any override templates. This is working fine, but I want to programatically set the child theme path to be this instead:

```
wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen_child/twentyfifteen_grandchild
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the answer although there might be a better way of doing this. I tried the following in functions.php and that didn't work. But if I add the same thing in a plugin it works.

```
add_filter( 'stylesheet_directory', 'custom_stylesheet_directory' );
function custom_stylesheet_directory($dir)
{
    $project = $dmmEnv->getProject();
    $dir = str_replace(
       'twentyfifteen_child' , 
       'twentyfifteen_child/twentyfifteen_grandchild', $dir);

    return $dir;
}
```